# How to cancel PJSIP thread

Tags: c, pjsip

I am able to successfully create a pjsip thread.
My pjsip thread is executing correctly.
But when i am trying to cancel the thread,I am not able to cancel the thread.
According to pjsip docs i need to call destroy method but it doesn't work.
How to cancel the pjsip thread??

This is the link to pjsip thread docs.
http://www.pjsip.org/pjlib/docs/html/group__PJ__THREAD.htm

Comment: What about some [MCVE]?